# How to make integrations tests in Rails afther create the model user with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing

I am doing an integration test that worked before installing devise. Now throw error for a duplicate key. Trying to insert a user. The thing is that I am doing and testing the tests is for a Category model that does not even have an association. I leave the code and the error. Thank you

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreateCategoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

 test "get new category form and create category" do
  get new_category_path
  assert_template 'categories/new'
  assert_difference 'Category.count', 1 do
     post categories_path, params: { category: { name: "measure tension", description: "This is the Category for measure tension"} }
     follow_redirect!
  end
  assert_template 'categories/index'
  assert_match "measure tension", response.body
 end

end
```

The error is as follows:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 14544
Run options: --seed 57420

# Running:

E

Error:
CreateCategoriesTest#test_get_new_category_form_and_create_category:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «index_users_on_email»
DETAIL:  Ya existe la llave (email)=().
: DELETE FROM "categories";
DELETE FROM "users";
INSERT INTO "categories" ("id", "name", "description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (980190962, 'MyString', 'MyText', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.457344', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.457344'), (298486374, 'MyString', 'MyText', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.457344', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.457344');
INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (980190962, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, '2020-03-06 20:25:00.463209', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.463209'), (298486374, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, '2020-03-06 20:25:00.463209', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.463209')


Error:
CreateCategoriesTest#test_get_new_category_form_and_create_category:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass



bin/rails test test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:5



Finished in 0.023791s, 42.0323 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: check test_helper.rb if it create users? or check the fixtures/users if it has users with same email if you're using fixture

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Indeed I had fixtures :all, but in my users.yml I had not configured the users well. I leave in the answer the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

Thakns to [kevinluo201](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8826293/kevinluo201) 
I solved my problem by configuring two different email users in users.yml
Although also in test_helper.rb the line "fixtures: all" is commented. You can also run the tests.

The users.yml:

```
one:
 email: email1@example.com

two: 
 email: email2@example.com
```